# MonoDevelop, linux, Ubuntu 18.04 Mint, in ConsoleApplication console doesn't pop

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, linux-mint

So, when I try to run my program on MonoDev, it shows me the error:

> Couldn`t connect to the debugger

When I toggle the CheckBox "running on external console", it just ignores all of my `Console.ReadLine()`s and continues running code further.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The internal console is read-only, therefore `Console.Readline()` will not work, only `Console.Write()` or `Console.WriteLine()` will show up in the console.

There are several issues regarding the use of the external console depending on the selected terminal. As a fall-back scenario xterm is used. Therefore first thing to check: is xterm installed?

Here is a link which might help to get a deeper insight: https://superuser.com/questions/669444/monodevelop-cannot-connect-to-debugger